# what is the difference between joint probability distribution and random vector

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $(S,\mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathbf X:S\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ random vector. Let $X_i:S\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be random variables such that $\mathbf X=(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)$.

Is there any difference between distribution of random vector $\mathbf X$ and joint probability distribution of random variables $X_i$?

More generally, is joint probability distribution of random variables just a different word for distribution of some random vector?

Comment: Yes, I think there is no difference. But I am curious for a confirmation/counterargument to see if I also have a misconception on this.

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$ is exactly the same as the joint distribution of $n$ real-valued random variables. Both of these are equivalent to measures on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n))$.